# Powershell: Out-Printer, unicode and font sizing

Tags: powershell, unicode

```
powershell "get-content foo.txt|Out-Printer"
```

As long as foo.txt is english, everything is fine (well mostly)

If foo.txt contains unicode characters e.g. राष्ट्र then what gets printed is stuff like °à¥€ à¤¬

I tried passing the -Encoding option to get-content but it did not change the result.

- Is it possible ensure that unicode text gets printed properly without
  launching Word/IE etc in the background to print it?

My second question is

- Is it possible to control which font (type and size) is used for
  printing by out-printer?

Comment: I think this depends on the printer. The default configuration is likely to support only ASCII or some extended Latin charset. Many printers can be controlled with custom languages; HP has PCL, Kyocera has Prescribe, many higher-end devices support PostScript. So in order to print Unicode, a special control sequence could be the solution.

Comment: Opt-Printer was supposed to seamlessly write to any printer that was connected.
If I have to start adding logic to determine the printer type and which language it supports and then inject the printer specific magic codes in my text file, then it defeats the entire purpose of out-printer.

The thing is, I can do "notepad /p foo.txt and get the unicode code characters printed properly... So there is atleast one team in Microsoft which knows how to correctly send Text to the printer :(

Comment: 1) When using Get-Content with the -Encoding parameter (without Out-Printer), does the display show the characters correctly? The print out is just a 'spooling', so if the display shows gibberish, it will print the same.      
2) Does the printer support non-ASCII character printing by default?

Comment: Powershell 5 `get-content` won't recognize utf8 no bom without the `-encoding` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment (Windows 10 2004 Build 19041.985, Japanese locale), I got the correct result with the following situation:

- Save the `.txt` file in UTF-8 with BOM, and print with `Get-Content .\foo.txt | Out-Printer`
- Save the `.txt` file in UTF-8 without BOM, and print with `Get-Content .\foo.txt -Encoding UTF8 | Out-Printer`

[image]

I got the incorrect result (like `爨ｰ爨ｾ爨ｷ爭財､游･財､ｰ`) with the following situation:

- Save the `.txt` file in UTF-8 without BOM, and print with `Get-Content .\foo.txt | Out-Printer`

[image]

So it looks like an encoding problem. Please check what @RavenKnit said first.

> Is it possible ensure that unicode text gets printed properly without launching Word/IE etc in the background to print it?

I couldn't find the way to do with the `Get-PrinterPort`, `Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer`, `prnmngr.vbs` or `prnqctl.vbs`. If you just don't want to show a Windows while you print the content of a file, you can use the `Print` verb. It runs `notepad.exe` for `.txt` files, `winword.exe` for `.docx` files, etc.

```
Start-Process .\foo.txt -Verb Print -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait
```

> Is it possible to control which font (type and size) is used for printing by out-printer?

According to [the source of `Out-Printer`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/FormatAndOutput/out-printer/PrinterLineOutput.cs#L81), the default font is [embbeded in the `.resx` file](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/resources/OutPrinterDisplayStrings.resx#L121). So it looks like you cannot control the default font.